# React Router Route does return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very beginner in React and while I was practicing Router, I found that  does not return the related component.
below is the code.
p.s. BrowserRouter works properly is the  Hello world  has been rendered.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import About from './About';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
          <div> Hello world</div>
      <Route exact path="/"  component={MainPage}/>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For react router dom 6 it should be element:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
// import your route components too

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
          <Route path="new" element={<NewTeamForm />} />
          <Route index element={<LeagueStandings />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**Sources:** https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 1):

if you use react-router-dom^6

```
  import {Route, BrowserRouter, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div> Hello world</div>
  <Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
    <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
  </Routes> 
  </BrowserRouter>
```

or you use react-router-dom^5

```
 import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
  
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div> Hello world</div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  component={MainPage}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Switch> 
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I am using V6, and also tried Routes, But it also didn't work

Comment: Sorry, i fixed. you use component. But v6 using element. Try This https://codesandbox.io/s/so1-reactrouterdom-forked-u34ed

Answer (score 0):

add `/` before `about` route and add `Switch` or `Routes` (according to the installed version) to it

[Configuring React Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/installation)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import About from './About';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/"  component={MainPage}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>  
  );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I did it but unfortunately did not work

Comment: what is the version of  react-router?

Comment: 6, I surrounded "Route" tags by <Routes> but it did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `Route` with `Routes` or `Switch`(depending on which version of react-router-dom are you using)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MainPage from './MainPage';
import About from './About';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/"  component={MainPage}/>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>  
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Make sure to import it as well!

Comment: I am using v6 and used <Routes> to handle that, but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you append  component after def. of the last Route.

like this...

```
 <Route path="about" component={About}/>
 <Outlet/>
```